# What component is I5B38?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I am in the process of repairing a circuit board.
Can you give me a replacement for the component outlined in red?

The imprint on the board is DZ with consecutive numbering (here DZ18).
Is it maybe a zener diode?

The component is installed on the power board of a 4kW controller of an e-scooter.(Power Board 4.2)
The size is about 5x2.5mm - SMA.

[image: photo of the component]

Comment: DZ is definitely a zener diode; I couldn't say what part number it is though. The image is hard to read, but could that B be a logo? I think the Burr-Brown logo looked somewhat like that.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think it says "15B" rather then "I5B", in which case the marking corresponds to [PTZ15B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/ptz15b-210342.pdf). The "38" indicates a manufacturing date according to the datasheet.

Comment: Thank you very much